# Функция, которая принимает массив со строкой и возвращает новый массив с длиной элементов тех строк

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, мне нужно написать функцию, которая принимает массив arr со строкой и возвращает новый массив с длиной элементов тех строк.

К примеру
const аrr1 = getLength (['sun', 'underground', 'place']) - запишет в переменную массив [3,11,5].

Вот что получилось у меня, но не работает:

```
function getLength(arr) {
    let toStr = arr.toString();
    let j = 0;
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= toStr.length; i++) {
        if (toStr[j == toStr.length-1]) break;
        if (toStr[i] == (',')) {
            j = i - j;
            result += j + ' ';
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
}
const arr1 = getLength(['sun', 'underground', 'place']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getLength = source => source.map(str => str.length);

console.log(getLength(['one', 'sound', 'underground']));
```

Comment: что-то не получается

Comment: Что именно, уточните?

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо!